# Creating a web-end for a C++ program

Tags: php, c++, web-applications

I was wondering what would be the best method for creating a web end for interfacing with a C++ program on the server. At first I simply thought just using shell execution from the web server side language (like `shell_exec()` in PHP), but I was wondering if there is a "better" way. Maybe something more native or is this a bad practice for some reason?

Comment: Should be on stackoverflow not here AFAIK. Might be wrong though.

Comment: I figured it would be better on programmers.SE because it is more theoretical and doesn't really require a code based answer. This is more based on the ideas surrounding achieving this task, not an exact method of how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Web programming with C++ has pretty much gone out of style. The traditional way to do it was with CGI. See here for a [tutorial](http://www.geekdaily.net/2007/08/06/c-a-basic-cgi-tutorial/).

Or you can add an embedded webserver like [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/)

However, I think it's easiest to use PHP's passthru. For example, on one of my sites I have a C++ program that generates images, to display the images I do:

```
<?

header("content-type: image/png"); 

$temp = $_GET["temp"];
$rain = $_GET["rain"];

passthru("/home/rrabien/marker $temp $rain")

?>
```

Comment: This looks pretty good to me, thanks for the passthru function. I had never heard of that one. All in all this is what I had originally had in mind, but its good to know that this is really the best way to achieve what I desired. Thanks FigBug.

Comment: Do NOT use passthru without correctly escaping input, or you're asking to be hacked. Read this link: http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/php-security-1.htm

Comment: This is how I do it, but I use django.  Instead of passing through to the c++ application directly, I have a python wrapper for either launching my c++ app, or communicating through IPC or network with a daemon using some internal api.Works really well.

Answer (score 3):

[Wt, the C++ web toolkit](http://webtoolkit.eu/wt/) is a library with a set of classes that make it much easier to add a web interface of any complexity to a C++ program. It focuses on the web interface aspects only, and is otherwise non-intrusive to your program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are compilable web framework out there for C/C++.  However, I'm not familiar with any.

What I am familiar with is the ease of which you can [extend Python with C/C++](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html).  I believe it can be made [even simpler by using SWiG](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python).  Given that Python has a plethora of web frameworks this may be an option for you.